# How import firebase cloud function config dynamically in NodeJS 14 with `type: module`? [ closed ]

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, node-modules

I would like to achieve importing cloud function config dynamically but it won't working as expected.

```
import config from "firebase-functions";
```

It works ✔️

```
const {config} = await import('firebase-functions');
```

It won't work ❌

also tried the following but won't works.

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions"; // function is already using as static import
or 
const functions = await import('firebase-functions');
functions.config ❌// => undefined
functions.auth ✔️
functions.firestore ✔️
//and analytics, app, auth, database, firestore, handler, https, pubsub, remoteConfig, storage, testLab, logger ✔️
```

Am not getting a way to dynamically import the config import along with function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh finaly it works.

```
const { default: functions} = await import('firebase-functions');
```

and

```
import functions from "firebase-functions";
```

giving functions.config